# xcode iOS getting a list of all localizations

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

How do I get a list of all available localizations?

I have an app with five localizations. I need to know whether the current locale is in that list and if not, create a fallback.
But how do I find out if the current locale is in that list?

Comment: [NSLocale currentLocale];

Comment: Then compare with array of all localizations

Comment: well - I though that - but that's a little cumbersome, isn't it?
Isn't there a way to find out out which languages have been localized programmatically instead of keeping a list?

Comment: @Swissdude Use `NSFileManager` to list all `*.lproj` directories in the app bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to find out if the current locale is supported or not would be to add a special "test" string (say, `@"IsSupported" = @"Yes"`) to all five localizations that you support. Then a simple check will work:

```
BOOL supported = [NSLocalizedString(@"IsSupported", nil) isEqualToString:@"Yes"];
```

Comment: Shouldn't this fallback to the development language and return "Yes" if the locale is not defined?

Answer (score 12):

For me accepted solution didn't work, if Language was not supported - App simply fall back to English and, as English strings file contained "IsSupported" string - it returned "YES".

I had to use this solution

```
NSString* currentLanguage = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
NSArray* supportedLocalizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations];

if ([supportedLocalizations containsObject:currentLanguage]) {
    isLocalizedToCurrentLanguage = YES;
}
else {
    isLocalizedToCurrentLanguage = NO;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work - `preferredLanguages` returns strings like 'pt-BR', 'en-US' but localizations returns strings like 'pt', 'en'.

Comment: Read `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]` instead of `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`. That will return "en", "cs", etc...